# Android Lint - Ignoring noinspection AndroidLintDefaultLocale

Tags: android

In a portion of my code I need to force a string to be lowercase - this String comes from a constant, and as such will always be English.

```
String table = DirectoryTableModule.DirectoryContract.TABLE_NAME.toLowerCase();
```

This of course trips a lint warning for:

> Implicitly using the default locale is a common source of bugs: Use `toLowerCase(Locale)` instead
>
> Calling `String#toLowerCase()` or `#toUpperCase()` *without specifying an explicit locale* is a common source of bugs. The reason for that is that those methods will use the current locale on the user's device, and even though the code appears to work correctly when you are developing the app, it will fail in some locales. For example, in the Turkish locale, the uppercase replacement for `i` is *not* `I`. If you want the methods to just perform ASCII replacement, for example to convert an enum name, call `String#toUpperCase(Locale.US)` instead. If you really want to use the current locale, call `String#toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault())` instead.

So naturally I added the appropriate ignore comment above this line of code:

```
//noinspection AndroidLintDefaultLocale
String table = DirectoryTableModule.DirectoryContract.TABLE_NAME.toLowerCase();
```

This seems to satisfy the IDE (Android Studio 1.2.1.1), but lint running on our CI server (Jenkins) still shows this as a warning.

If it helps, Jenkins shows it has version 24.3 of the lint binary that comes with the Android SDK.

How do I get lint running on the CI server to accept this noinspection comment?

Comment: Im seeing the same problem. This seems to be broken

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to just give it a `Locale`.

You could use a `@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")` annotation, [docs here](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings)

Comment: I want to avoid the annotation, as it will turn it off for the warning for the whole method (or class).

Comment: In that case, it looks to me like fixing the issue lint is pointing at is the simplest way.  `toLowerCase(Locale.English);` or whichever English locale your string is in